# Using DateTimeOffset.Parse and Explicitly Specify TimeZoneInfo

Tags: c#

I need to use DateTimeOffset.Parse to parse in a date and time, but I need to explicitly specify the TimeZoneInfo that this date and time belongs to.

I have created a TimeZoneInfo in "GMT Standard Time" and have tried to use this as part of the DateTimeOffset.Parse method but cannot find out how to do this.

The following code assumes that the parsed date and time is Local time. I need to be able to use my TimeZoneInfo object so that I can specify from which timezone it came from.

```
DateTimeOffset date = DateTimeOffset.Parse("02/07/2019 10:30:00");
```

I can then store that DateTimeOffset and then convert it to any timezone!

Many thanks

Comment: TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTme(); Check it out here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Dude finally, thank you so much. I have been stuck on this for so long - I didn't realize this was so easy. Cheers

Comment: while you're learning, take the time to always check the docs. You can almost always find what you're looking for there. I'm glad this was a solution for you.

Comment: @xTwisteDx believe me I have been looking through the documentation but the timezone specifics around DateTIme and DateTimeOffset confuse the heck out of me. I understand the concept, but actually getting it to do what you need it for can be difficult I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`

Check it out here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks again, this is exactly what I was looking for. Quick question though, if instead of DateTimeOffset.Parse(), what if I wanted to use "new DateTime(2019,7,2,10,30,00)" and stop it from assuming my new DateTime is local?

Comment: You'd have to store it in a simple DateTime format so `DateTime someVar = DateTime(.....)` I believe that syntax is correct, don't have VS open atm lol